# How can(should) I convert .py files to a windows .exe file on a Linux machine?

Tags: python, wine, python3

> I am on Linux Mint 19.03,
>
> Python version that I use is 3.7,
>
> I have winehq-stable installed(5.0). I don't have a lot information on Wine

I was trying to make a `.exe` file to distribute to Windows 10 users. At, first, I used `pyinstaller` to make a standalone executable, however, I then realized that the executables created on a Linux machine does not work on a Windows machine.

So, now, I need some way to create and test `.exe` files without using another machine with a Windows OS.

I saw some people do it by installing `python` into `wine`, however most resources were written for python2 and also they were not clear enough to me understand actually. I actually don't know how to install `python3.7` into `wine` either.

Or, as another option, using a virtual machine might be a solution. Should I go with it instead of dealing with wine?

So, I hope somebody can give me a method to how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a virtual machine (for Mint you could use Virtualbox, or you might have Gnome boxes) as once you get it set up you administer the box as normal. You would want to install the following on the box:

- Cygwin so you can have a familiar bash environment
- Python so you can test the python source without compiling on the Windows box as well (quality control is essential)
- Pyinstaller so you can build the `.exe` file

And you would probably want to set up a shared directory between host and box, use it to store both the python source and the `.exe`

[Virtualbox homepage](https://www.virtualbox.org)

[Shared directory](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.1/user/sharedfolders.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer, however, I don't get what you really want to imply by "you would want the following ports on the box:" and also, the file transfer between vm and host machine was one of the questions on my mind, can you ellaborate a little bit how to do that?

Comment: Sure, I’ll edit the answer

Comment: thanks for the edit, shared directory looks like a bunch of work, I think I'm gonna go with cloud services to transfer files.